# CSS !important rule on Email

Tags: css, email

Is this supported on most email clients? (gmail, yahoo, live... )

Comment: Those aren't email clients, unless you're specifically referring to the webmail frontends to those services, and not desktop/mobile apps.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. Thanks all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they are supported in Gmail, Yahoo, AOL, Hotmail, and Mac os X Mail as far I've tested with browsers such as Firefox, Safari, Chrome, IE 6 - 9, and Opera